# Cannot list keys within object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state variable `projects` which should store a dictionary of arrays, where the key is id of the organisation that owns the project, and the array consists of objects storing information about the project. For example:

```
{
    orgId123: [
        project1: {
            name: "my cool project",
            status: "submitted"
        },
        projectAwesome: {
            name: "Stan's project",
            status: "draft"
        }
    ],
    orgUSA: [
        newProj234: {
            name: "another great project",
            status: "submitted"
        }
    ]
}
```

I try to get a list of all organisation IDs using `Objects.keys(projects)`, however that returns an empty array.

I suspect that somehow my `projects` variable is structured wrongly. When I `console.log` the contents of `projects`, I get:

[image]

Notice how the root level object says just `{}`.

When I tried to re-create what the `projects` variable should look like and logged that, I saw a slightly different output:

[image]

In this manually created object, the root-level object is shown as `{orgId1}: Array(1)` instead of the previously-shown `{}` (on the actual object).

What does this say about how the object is structured and why can I not get a list of keys from the first object using `Object.keys()`?

For context, I create the original variable using the following code:

```
async function fetchProjects() {

    // Load list of organisations that the user is a member of
    const organisationsSnapshot = await getDocs(query(
        collection(db, 'organisations'),
        where(`members.${user.uid}`, '!=', null)
    ))
    const organisations = organisationsSnapshot.docs.map(organisationSnap => ({
        ...organisationSnap.data(),
        id: organisationSnap.id
    }))

    // Load list of projects for each organisation the user is a member of
    const projectsDict = {}
    organisations.forEach(async (organisation) => {
        const projectsQuery = query(collection(db, `organisations/${organisation.id}/projects`))
        const projectsSnap = await getDocs(projectsQuery)
        projectsDict[organisation.id] = projectsSnap.docs.map(projectSnap => ({
            ...projectSnap.data(),
            id: projectSnap.id
        }))
    })
    setProjects(projectsDict)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have an array of `key:value`s. You should wrap it in `{}`.

```js
[ key1: value1, key2: value2, ] //Unexpected Token
[ { key1: value1 }, { key2: value2 }, ] //Good to go
```

So instead of:

```js
{
    orgId123: [
        project1: {
            name: "my cool project",
            status: "submitted"
        },
        projectAwesome: {
            name: "Stan's project",
            status: "draft"
        }
    ],
    orgUSA: [
        newProj234: {
            name: "another great project",
            status: "submitted"
        }
    ]
}
```

You should have:

```js
{
    orgId123: [
        {  
          project1: {
            name: "my cool project",
            status: "submitted"
          }
        },
        {  
          projectAwesome: {
            name: "Stan's project",
            status: "draft"
          }
        }
    ],
    orgUSA: [
        { 
          newProj234: {
            name: "another great project",
            status: "submitted"
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

OR

```js
{
    orgId123: {
        project1: {
            name: "my cool project",
            status: "submitted"
        },
        projectAwesome: {
            name: "Stan's project",
            status: "draft"
        }
    },
    orgUSA: {
        newProj234: {
            name: "another great project",
            status: "submitted"
        }
    }
}
```

Honestly, I would structure your `projects` as follows:

```js
const organisations = [{
    orgId: "orgId123",
    projects: [{
      projectId: "project1",
      name: "my cool project",
      status: "submitted"
    }, {
      projectId: "projectAwesome",
      name: "Stan's project",
      status: "draft"
    }]
  },
  {
    orgId: "orgUSA",
    projects: [{
      projectId: "newProj234",
      name: "another great project",
      status: "submitted"
    }]
  }
]

//This way, organisations is an array of organisations,
//which is an object that has orgId, projects which is an array of its projects.

//It will be much more intuitive to work with while iterating over it.
//Such as if you need to display all the orgIds,
console.log("Organisation IDs:")
for (const org of organisations) {
  console.log(org.orgId)
}
console.log("=================");

//If you need all project IDs and names:
console.log("Projects:")
for (const org of organisations) {
  console.log(`Organisation ${org.orgId} has the following projects:`)
  for (const proj of org.projects) {
    console.log(`Project ID ${proj.projectId}: ${proj.name}`)
  }
  console.log("=================");
}
console.log("=================");
```

Comment: Nice spot. OP should look into how `for (const index in projects){}` works for this scenario. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Thanks. How can I modify my `fetchProjects()` function to fix the `projects` variable? If I simply enclose the value in curly braces (i.e., `setProjects({ projectsDict })`, I get an unnecessary level of nesting when all the data is stored at key `projects['projectsDict']`. Is there a more elegant solution for this?

Comment: Thank you both. Not entirely sure how it works, but I managed to incorporate Zei's hint and used a `for(organisationIndex in organisations) { const organisation = organisations[organisationIndex] ... }` loop instead of a `forEach`, and now it works.

Comment: @Sam I have edited my answer to include a suggested way to structure your `projects`.

Comment: @Sam cSharp's example is good. You should stop using `forEach` and start using `for in` and `for of`. Use `for of` to loop over arrays of objects e.g. `[{id:1, name:"john"}, {id:2, name:"sam"}]` and `for in` to loop over an object by index, `{"organisation1" : {id: 1}, "organisation2": {id: 2}}`.